# Does Cucumber with Protractor need the callback?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, protractor

I'm trying to understand how [The WebDriver Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) works exactly.

According to the linked documentation (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) no callback method / call is needed in jasmine:

> Protractor adapts Jasmine so that each spec automatically waits until the control flow is empty before exiting.

However, I have to use cucumber. I'm using the library `protractor-cucumber-framework` as described here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md#using-cucumber

It works well, but for some reason it works better when I skip the callback variable then when I try using it. For instance, this code fails:

```
this.Given(/^the login page is active$/, function (callback) {
  browser.get('/').then(callback);
});
```

With the error ...

> TypeError: text.split is not a function
>
> [launcher] Process exited with error code 1

On the other hand, this codes works as I want it to work and cucumber / protractor seems to be waiting until the page is loaded, before executing further functions:

```
me.Given(/^the login page is active$/, function () {
  browser.get('/');
});
```

But I couldn't find any documentation confirming that I really can omit the callback function.

Currently the page I tried to test doesn't use Angular and therefore I have the following code in my config file:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor uses WebDriverJS underneath. And WebDriverJS uses a promise manager where it queues its commands. Here is some excerpts from their wiki page [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/WebDriverJs.wiki)

> Internally, the promise manager maintains a call stack. Upon each turn
>   of the manager's execution loop, it will pull a task to execute from
>   the queue of the top-most frame. Any commands scheduled within the
>   callback of a previous command will be scheduled in a new frame,
>   ensuring they run before any tasks previously scheduled. The end
>   result is that if your test is written-in line, with all callbacks
>   defined by function literals, commands should execute in the order
>   they are read vertically on the screen. For example, consider the
>   following WebDriverJS test case:

```
driver.get(MY_APP_URL);
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
  if (title === 'Login page') {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('user')).sendKeys('bugs');
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('pw')).sendKeys('bunny');
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('login')).click();
  }
});
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('userPreferences')).click();
```

This test case could be rewritten using !WebDriver's Java API as follows:

```
driver.get(MY_APP_URL);
if ("Login Page".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
  driver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys("bugs");
  driver.findElement(By.id("pw")).sendKeys("bunny");
  driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
}
driver.findElement(By.id("userPreferences")).click();
```

Now going back to your question, since you are omitting `callback` from your steps, cucumber is treating your test code as synchronous. See documentation [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#synchronous-step-definitions). And because the way protractor/WebdriverJS handles promise manager the way described above, everything works as expected for you.

As far as the error you are getting when using `callback`, I'm not sure. I do it exactly the same way you are doing. See [here](https://github.com/paypal/nemo-cucumberjs/blob/master/test/functional/step_definitions/paypalRegStepDefs.js#L13). I'm using cucumber `^0.9.2`. It could be that your cucumber version has issues.

On a side note, I found that you could return promises instead of using callbacks to let cucumber know that you are done executing. So something like this works as well (assuming you are using `^0.9.2`). I tested it,

```
me.Given(/^the login page is active$/, function () {
  return browser.get('/');
});
```

Comment: Very detailed overview, awesome job!

Comment: Thx, I have version `^0.9.4` - I just set up the system yesterday so it should be the latest. I'll write more tests today and try returning promises - thx